Classic Open CTI methods workaround in Lightning
we're preparing for a migration from Classic to Lightning. We have a custom implementation of CTI where we're using some of the sforce methods, that we need to replace with the new ones.
I've encountered a problem specifically with method sforce.console.cti.fireOnCallBegin() as it doesn't have an equivalent in the Lightning. I've done some digging but haven't found any workaround yet.
Did any of you encounter and solved such a problem? Appreciate any help.
